# Box-shadow positioned based on window scroll algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I have this amateur function that changes the box-shadow on a group of elements based on the window.scrollTop position and element offset. When the user scrolls up or down from the photos, the box-shadow will move down or up respectively. So it gives the illusion of perspective. When these photo elements are in the center of the screen, the box-shadow is centered.

Right now it's not ideal and by that I mean it isn't very symmetrical and doesn't feel right. I know it because my "golden-ratio" (Not the actual Phy golden ratio, i just used this as a variable name) is just a random number. I know there is a way to use my variables to set this up properly I just can't come up with it. Looking for golden ratio (box-shadow vertical offset) to be from about -20 to 20, 0 when centered, seems to look okay.

So my question is can anyone optimize my algorithm so that the box-shadow changes as described above but more realistic?

- This should only happen inside a certain vertical scroll window so
  that this function isn't running while the photos are off the screen (already pretty much implemented)
- The box-shadow change is subtle so there is not a HUGE shadow above or below it.
- In my real code I have another function that changes the photos to be the same height as the width on window resize. Here I just have a fixed height of 160px.

Here is my code (modified to give a barebones example). Feel free to redo my function from scratch if that is cleaner.

```js
var halfHeight;
var eleHalfHeight;
var scrollTop;
var photosOffset;
var profOffset
var distPhotos;
var goldenRatio;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  halfHeight = $(window).height() / 2;
  eleHalfHeight = $('.photo').height() / 2;
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  photosOffset = $('.photos').offset().top - halfHeight + eleHalfHeight;
  distPhotos = (photosOffset - scrollTop);

  if (distPhotos < photosOffset && distPhotos > -photosOffset) {
    goldenRatio = distPhotos / 25;
    $('.photo-frame').css('box-shadow', '0px ' + (goldenRatio + 6) + 'px 4px 2px #c9c9c9');
  };

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 500vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.photos {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.photos .photo-frame {
  width: 25%;
  height: 160px;
  border: 20px solid whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px gray;
  background-color: #000;
}

.photos .photo-frame .photo {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="photos">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ref: *can anyone optimize my algorithm so that the box-shadow changes as described above but mathematically perfect* - Do you want a mathematically perfect *Phy*? In web, there's no such thing. It will be rounded to 8 decimals and that's more than enough. So use: `1.618033989`

Comment: I don't know what a Phy is. But yea I guess i don't mean mathematically perfect, rather just makes sense in the context of the scroll. Some number for the vertical offset that is 0 when the photos are centered, and maybe something like -20 and 20 max for when the photos are below and above the center

Comment: [Phy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) is the golden ratio. Let's focus on your question. Usually askers on [so] know how they want it to look but ask about the technical stuff. You seem to have covered the technical part. Are you not happy with the looks and want someone to make it look better and feel more natural? Your current code seems to do what you ask for and it's not clear what you consider to be wrong with it.

Comment: Okay we can call it the platinum ratio from now on. It doesn't look perfect. I.e. the offset isn't the same scrolling one way as it is the other. If you scroll up 200px from center, the offset might be -10. When you scroll down 200px from center, the offset might be 30 when it should be 10.

Comment: You forgot to describe what you call *perfect*, @Stefan. Have you stated anywhere that the shadow should be symmetrical? Because, by the way, in real life most shadows are longer downwards. People here are programmers, not mind-readers. You need to spell out what you want. *"It's not perfect"* is not going to get you kudos, nor answers. As a side-note, ***nothing** is perfect*.

Comment: Hmm okay i guess perfect is too literal a term. Symmetrical was the word I was looking for thank you.  Sorry if my description didn't make it clear... I never assumed anyone here was a mind reader or expecting kudos? From this?

Comment: I was trying to be helpful and understand what you wanted. Didn't mean to sound aggressive, on the contrary. I suppose I was way too chatty. I apologize.

Comment: All good @AndreiGheorghiu. Someone had a nice answer I was going to review this morning why did they take it down :(

Comment: I thought you saw it and deemed unworthy. When I think my help is not welcome I stop helping. And I got a feeling that doesn't make me too special. :) I'll add it back when at machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it *perfect™*?
Nope.

Do I like it better than yours?
A little bit.

Will it help you?
I hope so, since I think it's easier to tweak — at least this was my intention. You tell me.

```js
let wH = $(window).height(),
    sO = 210, // shadowOffset (px); 50 => from -25 to +25
    tO = 4,   // topOffset (px)  0 => vertical symmetry,
    lO = 4,   // leftOffset (px) 0 => horizontal symmetry
    moveshadow = function() {
      let diff = $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top,
        tOH = $(this)[0].offsetHeight,
        should = (-diff < wH) && (diff < tOH),
        factor = should ? 
          -((diff / wH + 1) / (1 + tOH / wH) - .5) * sO + tO : 
          0;
      if (should) {
        $(this).css({
          "box-shadow": lO +"px " +
            factor +
            "px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.1), " + lO + "px " +
            (factor + sO / 20) +
            "px 17px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.07), " + lO + "px " +
            (factor - sO / 20) +
            "px 22px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.06), " + lO/2 + "px " +
            factor / 20 +
            "px 21px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
        })
      }
    };

$(window)
  .on('resize', function() {
    wH = $(window).height()
  })
  .on('scroll resize', function() {
    $('.photo-frame').each(moveshadow)
  })
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 120vh 30px;
}

.photos {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.photo {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 32.36vw;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.photo-frame {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(min-width: 1000px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .photo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 323.6px;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 641px) {
  .photo-frame:first-child { transform: translateY(-10vw) }
  .photo-frame:last-child { transform: translateY(10vw) }
}
@media(max-width: 640px) {
  .photos {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .photo {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 37.08vw;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  .photo-frame {
    margin: 7.5vw 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="photos">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

<kbd>[playground](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/hcvbgfvu/)</kbd>

:: }<(((*> ::)

Comment: Thank a lot Andrei this is perfect™ :) just kidding but this looks great. Pretty genius function and I appreciate the ability to tweak with ease... I will implement it and get back if I have any questions and if not mark as answer

Comment: I liked your question and enjoyed coding this. I personally find jsFiddle a bit easier to play with, as it also gives ability to resize the panel, that's why I added it. I also put a bit of effort into trying to minimize the calculation impact (as much as possible). In fact, animating `box-shadow` is a big `no-no`. It's way too expensive on resources. I tried debouncing the calls but it's not looking so good. You are welcome.

Comment: Alright this worked nicely! And again I like the flexibility. A little torn about the extra complexity of multiple box-shadows but it turns out to be a nice and more realistic effect as I asked for. It's true this is kind of a heavy animation but it will be the only heavy function happening on this website so I'm fine with it. Thanks again appreciate it!